# Why is SQL evaluating a WHERE clause that is False?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a query in SQL (2008) that I can't understand why it's taking so much longer to evaluate if I include a clause in a WHERE statement that shouldn't affect the result. Here is an example of the query:

```
declare @includeAll bit = 0;

    SELECT
        Id
        ,Name
        ,Total
    FROM
        MyTable
    WHERE
        @includeAll = 1 OR Id = 3926
```

Obviously, in this case, the @includeAll = 1 will evaluate false; however, including that increases the time of the query as if it were always true. The result I get is correct with or without that clause: I only get the 1 entry with Id = 3926, but (in my real-world query) including that line increases the query time from < 0 seconds to about 7 minutes...so it seems it's running the query as if the statement were true, even though it's not, but still returning the correct results.

Any light that can be shed on why would be helpful. Also, if you have a suggestion on working around it I'd take it. I want to have a clause such as this one so that I can include a parameter in a stored procedure that will make it disregard the Id that it has and return all results if set to true, but I can't allow that to affect the performance when simply trying to get one record.

Comment: What are the execution plans for each?

Comment: Does WHERE @includeAll = 1 OR (@includeAll = 0 AND Id = 3926) make a difference?

Comment: Tried switching around the order of them, and adding parenthesis, no change with either.

Comment: You don't want it evaluating `@includeAll = 1` for every row.  See @woot answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to look at the query plan to be sure, but using OR will often make it scan like this in some DBMS.

Also, read @Bogdan Sahlean's response for some great details as why this happening.

This may not work, but you can try something like if you need to stick with straight SQL:

```
SELECT
    Id
   ,Name
   ,Total
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE Id = 3926
UNION ALL
SELECT
    Id
   ,Name
   ,Total
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE Id <> 3926
AND   @includeAll = 1
```

If you are using a stored procedure, you could conditionally run the SQL either way instead which is probably more efficient.

Something like:

```
if @includeAll = 0 then
    SELECT
        Id
       ,Name
       ,Total
    FROM
        MyTable
    WHERE Id = 3926
else
    SELECT
        Id
       ,Name
       ,Total
    FROM
        MyTable
```

Comment: The IF / THEN solution would be the best performing - long to read in your proc, but it's the way to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In checking the execution plan, you're right that it was performing a scan. IF/THEN logic is a simple enough fix.

Answer (score 4):

> Obviously, in this case, the @includeAll = 1 will evaluate false;
>   however, including that increases the time of the query as if it were
>   always true.

This happens because those two predicates force SQL Server to choose an `Index|Table Scan` operator. Why ?

The execution plan is generated for all possible values of `@includeAll` variable / parameter. So, the same execution plan is used when `@includeAll = 0` and when `@includeAll = 1`. If `@includeAll = 0` is true and if there is an index on `Id` column then SQL Server *could use* an `Index Seek` or `Index Seek` + `Key|RID Lookup` to find the rows. But if `@includeAll = 1` is true the optimal data access operator is `Index|Table Scan`. So if the execution plan must be *usable* for all values of `@includeAll` variable what is the data access operator used by SQL Server: Seek or Scan ? The answer is bellow where you can find a similar query:

```
DECLARE @includeAll BIT = 0;

-- Initial solution
SELECT  p.ProductID, p.Name, p.Color
FROM    Production.Product p
WHERE   @includeAll = 1 OR p.ProductID = 345 

-- My solution
DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SqlStatement = N'
SELECT  p.ProductID, p.Name, p.Color
FROM    Production.Product p
' + CASE WHEN @includeAll = 1 THEN '' ELSE 'WHERE   p.ProductID = @ProductID' END;

EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStatement, N'@ProductID INT', @ProductID = 345;
```

These queries have the following execution plans:

[image]

As you can see, first execution plan includes an `Clustered Index Scan` with two `not optimized` predicates.

My solution is based on dynamic queries and it generates two different queries depending on the value of `@includeAll` variable thus:

**[ 1 ]** When `@includeAll = 0` the generated query (`@SqlStatement`) is

```
SELECT  p.ProductID, p.Name, p.Color
FROM    Production.Product p
WHERE   p.ProductID = @ProductID
```

and the execution plan includes an `Index Seek` (as you can see in image above) and

**[ 2 ]** When `@includeAll = 1` the generated query (`@SqlStatement`) is

```
SELECT  p.ProductID, p.Name, p.Color
FROM    Production.Product p
```

and the execution plan includes an `Clustered Index Scan`. These two generated queries have different optimal execution plan.

Note: I've used [Adventure Works 2012](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/downloads/get/165399) sample database

Comment: Fantastic explanation of WHY it does this!

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be parameter sniffing - the procedure compiled when `@includeAll` was 1, and this is the query plan that has been cached. Meaning that when it is false you are still doing a full table scan when potentially and index seek and key lookup would be faster.

I think the best way of doing this is:

```
declare @includeAll bit = 0;

if @includeAll = 1
    BEGIN
        SELECT Id, Name,Total
        FROM MyTable;

    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT Id, Name,Total
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE Id = 3926;
    END
```

Or you can force recomplilation each time it is run:

```
SELECT Id, Name,Total
FROM MyTable
WHERE Id = 3926
OR @IncludeAll = 1
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

---

To demonstrate this further, I set up a very simple table and filled it with nonsense data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T (ID INT, Filler CHAR(1000));
INSERT dbo.T (ID)
SELECT TOP 100000 a.Number
FROM    master..spt_values a, master..spt_values b
WHERE   a.type = 'P'
AND     b.Type = 'P'
AND     b.Number BETWEEN 1 AND 100;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_T_ID ON dbo.T (ID);
```

I then ran the same query 4 times.

1. With `@IncludeAll` set to 1, query plan uses a table scan and plan is cached
2. Same query with `@IncludeAll` set to false, the plan with the table scan is still cached so that is used.
3. Clear the cache of plans, and run the query again with `@IncludeAll` false, so that the plan is now compiled and stored with an Index seek and bookmark lookup.
4. Run with `@IncludeAll` set to true. The Index seek and lookup are again used.

---

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT COUNT(Filler) FROM dbo.T WHERE @IncludeAll = 1 OR ID = 2;',
        @ParamDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX) = '@IncludeAll BIT',
        @PlanHandle VARBINARY(64);

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, 1;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, 0;

SELECT  @PlanHandle = cp.Plan_Handle
FROM    sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) AS st
WHERE   st.text LIKE '%' + @SQL;

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (@PlanHandle); -- CLEAR THE CACHE

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, 0;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, @ParamDefinition, 1;

DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (@PlanHandle); -- CLEAR THE CACHE
```

Inspecting the execution plans show that once the query has been compiled it will reuse the same plan regardless of parameter value, and that it will cache the plan that is appropriate for the value passed when it is run first, not on a most flexible basis.

[image]

Comment: I ran a test on my instance of sql server 2008r2 and got the exact opposite result. Specifically, I always got a scan whether I set @@includeAll = 0 first or @@IncludeAll = 1. I even used your code.

Answer (score 0):

Putting an OR statement in your SQL like this will cause a scan. It is probably scanning your entire table or index which will be extremely inefficient in a very large table.

If you look at the query plan for a query without the @includeAll portion at all, you would probably see an Index seek operation. As soon as you add that OR you are more than likely changing the query plan to a table/index scan. You should take a look at the plan for your query to see what exactly it is doing.

Comment: Is there any documentation about this? I've never heard of that optimizer criteria (but then I suck at SQL Server internals)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I do not know. I just tried the same query on a database with a surrogate key and it was scanning my clustered index when I added the OR piece.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I don't remember reading this either, but I know it's true.

Comment: Hm, I get a table scan with only `@includeAll=1` too (returning no results since it's false), so it may be related to the variable use, not the `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

Where Sql Server generates a queryplan, it must create a plan that would work for any possible values of any embedded variables. In your case an index seek would give you the best results when @IncludeAll = 0 however an index seek can not be used in the event @IncludeAll = 1. So the query optimizer has no choice but use the query plan that would work for either values of @IncludeAll. That results in a table scan.

Comment: *"it must create a plan that would work for any possible values of any embedded variables"* - this is not true, SQL Server will generate a plan based on the value passed when the query is compiled.

Comment: @GarethD Any more info on that? I can only find details on that re: parameter sniffing in procedures, not in ad hoc SQL.

Comment: @GarethD Yes, it is true. The values of parameters is used to build the best plan possible but the same plan has to return a *correct result* for all possible values of the parameter. When using `option(recompile)` SQL Server can build a plan that work only for the current value of the parameters since that plan will never be reused.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Please see the additions to my answer for a working example of how ad hoc query plan caching works, it shows that the plan cached is dependent on the parameter value when it is compiled.

Answer (score 0):

It is because sql server does not short circuit when you have OR in where clause.

Normally in other programming languages if we have a condition like

```
IF (@Param1 == 1 || @Param2 == 2)
```

If Param1 is = 1 it would not even bother evaluating the other expression.

In Sql Server if you have similar OR in your where clause like you have in your query

```
WHERE @includeAll = 1 OR Id = 3926
```

Even if @includeAll = 1 evaluates to true it might go ahead and check for the second condition anyway.

And changing the Order in your where clause that which expression is evaluated 1st doesnt make any difference because this is something Tunning optimiser will decied at run time. You cannot control this behaviour of sql server. Short circuiting expression evaluation or Order in which expressions are evaluated.